# requiring packages in src-electron

Tags: quasar-framework

I am a beginner to the Quasar FW (with electron) and trying to integrate Oauth2 to let users authenticate. The second file is getting called by the first. But the require statements in the second file throw errors.

I have implemented the workflow in two files:

1. a Vue file under `src/pages/Connect.vue`

```
    import oauth from '../../src-electron/oauth'
    
    export default defineComponent({
      name: 'ConnectPage',
      methods: {
        async login () {
          await oauth.authenticate()
        }
      }
    })
```

2. File `src/src-electron/oauth.js`

```
    const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
    const { google } = require('googleapis')
    
    const CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id'
    const CLIENT_SECRET = 'your_client_secret'
    const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback'
    
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      CLIENT_ID,
      CLIENT_SECRET,
      REDIRECT_URI
    )
    
    console.log(oauth2Client)
    
    export default {
      authenticate: async () => {
        console.log('authenticate')
        try {
          const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
          })
    
          const authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            show: false,
            webPreferences: {
              nodeIntegration: false // Make sure nodeIntegration is set to false to prevent security risks
            }
          })
    
          authWindow.loadURL(authUrl)
          authWindow.show()
    
          // Handle the response from the authorization flow
          authWindow.webContents.on('did-redirect-navigation', async (event, redirectUrl) => {
            const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(
              new URL(redirectUrl).searchParams.get('code')
            )
            console.log(tokens)
    
            // Use the access token to make Gmail API requests
            const gmail = google.gmail({
              version: 'v1',
              auth: oauth2Client
            })
            const messages = await gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me' })
    
            // ...
            console.log(messages)
    
            authWindow.close()
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      }
    }
```

I see an error on the electron console:
`ReferenceError: require is not defined vue-router.mjs:3451 at oauth.js:1:27`

It looks like the file does not like to require packages.

Answer (score 0):

Check this `main-process/electron-main.js` file:

```js
function createWindow () {
  /**
   * Initial window options
   */
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    useContentSize: true,
    webPreferences: {
      // Change from /quasar.conf.js > electron > nodeIntegration;
      // More info: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/node-integration
      nodeIntegration: process.env.QUASAR_NODE_INTEGRATION, // <-- should be true
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: process.env.QUASAR_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      // enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false, // <--- should be false

      // More info: /quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/electron-preload-script
      // preload: path.resolve(__dirname, 'electron-preload.js')
    }
  })
```

`QUASAR_NODE_INTEGRATION` must be true. controlled by: `quasar.conf.js`

```js
...
electron: {
      // -- @quasar/app v1.3+ --
      // More info: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/node-integration
      nodeIntegration: true,
}
...
```